# ErrorException failed to open stream: Permission denied on composer install

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I had a laravel app on github and I want to clone on other computer .
After I cloned the repository and run `composer install` command it shows me this error:

```
[ErrorException]                                                              
  copy(/Users/cosminciolacu/.composer/cache/files/symfony/debug/824e1c185cf2cd  
  10402999589458f4be7ef980e1.zip): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

what I missed?

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.composer/`
    run this command

Comment: @IrshadKhan You should make your comment an answer. Thank you! For Ubuntu it's: `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cache/composer/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may need to change the ownership and permissions of the directory you have installed the project in.

```
cd /path/to/project
sudo chmod -R 775 .
sudo chmod 660 .env
```

Comment: If I had another vote, I would give it to `sudo chmod 660 .env`

Answer (score -3):

If the first answer did not work, do `sudo composer install` instead of `composer install`.

**Warning**: well, said in comment section.

Comment: It's recommended to not install such tools with admin rights, because of security issues. The better solution is to properly setup the rights for the files and folders, as suggested by the other answer.

Comment: if nothing will works then it will work... by the way thanks for the clarifications.